# How to extract objects separated by semi-colon in another file in Java

Tags: java

As part of a project I'm working on, I want to parse/extract objects separated by semi-colons in a separate file on each line, so that I can create new objects corresponding to the ones on each line in the file whilst reading it.

I will have a file which will be taken as a parameter into a method - the file will will contain Character objects which are separated by semi-colons as demonstrated below in an example. The numbers represent `level` and `ExperiencePoints` respectively.

```
Mario(1,2);Luigi(2,3);Bowser(1,4);Toad(1,4);Yoshi(0,2)
Mario(2,2);Luigi(3,3);Bowser(1,4);Toad(1,4);Yoshi(0,2)
Mario(3,2);Luigi(4,3);Bowser(2,4);Toad(1,4);Yoshi(2,2)
Mario(4,2);Luigi(5,3);Bowser(2,4);Toad(2,4);Yoshi(2,2)
Mario(5,2);Luigi(6,3);Bowser(2,4);Toad(2,4);Yoshi(3,2)
Mario(6,2);Luigi(7,3);Bowser(3,4);Toad(2,4);Yoshi(3,2)
```

So far, I've written a method which looks like this; it takes a file as a parameter and reads it line by line. I cannot work out how to parse a file with values separated by semi-colons however; do I have to create a separate method to do this? Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
  public void main(String fileName)
      throws IOException {

    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Error accessing file");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the String split() method? "a;b".split(";") ==> String[2] { "a", "b" }

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if the scope requires buffered reader, but inside your try method you could do:

```
String myFileAsText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));

List<String> myObjects = Arrays.asList(myFileAsText.split("[;\r\n]"));
```

Which will give you an array of each element in String form, which you'll have to parse into your objects by iterating through.

Comment: Wouldn't you get "Yoshi()\nMario()". Why not "List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(...)" As it appears OPs file is using ines for inputs?

Comment: You are correct! Thank you for that, to keep things condensed since split takes regular expressions [;\r\n] should account for the newlines

Answer (score 1):

Lets ignore the file part and just consider a String line that you want to parse.

```
String line = "Mario(1,2);Luigi(2,3);Bowser(1,4);Toad(1,4);Yoshi(0,2)"
```

Now, you want to parse your line.

```
String[] tokens = line.split(";");
```

The resulting array will have:

```
{ "Mario(1,2)", "Luigi(2,3)", ...}
```

Now you want to parse the i'th token.

```
String token = tokens[i]
if(token.contains("Mario")){
  //parse out the ints possibly with a scanner and create a Mario
}
```

Another way to parse your line is to use a regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

while(m.find()){
    String name = m.group(1);
    int exp = Integer.parseInt( m.group(2) );
    int level = Integer.parseInt( m.group(3) );
    Character c = new Character( name , exp, level );
    characters.add( c );
}
```

If you need a different constructor based on the name you could do a switch statement.

```
Character c;
switch(name){
    case "Mario":
        c = new Mario(name, exp, level);
        break;
    case "Luigi":
        c = new Mario(name, exp, level);
        break;
    default:
        c = new Character(name, exp, level);
}
characters.add(c);
```

Another solution would be to serialize your objects using JSON.

Comment: In the method where I parse a line, could I start by doing this ```String text = null; BufferedReader brT = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); text = br.readLine();``` and then ```String[] tokens = text.split(";");```

Comment: Also, another thing - from what I understand, the array tokens would be created in the method where I parse a line. If so, how would I access the array tokens in the method where I parse a token?

Comment: I think using a regex would be a good way to parse the token; if I use this method, do I need to do ```String[] tokens = line.split(";");``` in parseLine()?

Comment: What other way can I parse each line in the file then; if I shouldn't use the tokens[] array in parseLine()?

Comment: I want to parse each object (or character in this instance) from each line - and then from there I want to create a new object corresponding to the character parameters in the file. e.g after parsing Bowser(2,1) from the file, I want to create an object called Bowser and set its experiencePoitns and level to 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: and yes, each line will have mario, luigi, bowser, toad, yoshi

Comment: There is a Character.java class which has constructor new Player(name, exp, level) and separate classes for each character e.g mario.java, bowser.java, luigi.java, toad.java, yoshi.java. Sorry, should've mentioned this earlier.

Comment: I updated the regex version to create new characters. If you need to call different constructors based on the name with a switch.

Comment: OK - I will try this later. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - as I want to call different constructors based on their name, I don't want to create Character(name, exp, level) as I do not have a constructor in Character.java with those parameters. Each character must only be a Mario, Luigi etc. In which case, how would I define 'Character c' so that it only adds those types of characters to the arraylist?

Comment: @Student It's hard to say without knowing what the relationship between Character and Mario is. If it is, `public class Mario implements Character` Then what I have written is sufficient. If it is just `public Mario` then, what are you doing with the marios you're creating? You cannot add them to a List<Character> but what are you going to dowith them?

Comment: I've done public Mario extends Character - would your implementation also work with this?

Comment: @Student yes you can write, `Character c = new Mario(...)` Since Mario is a character.